# Eclipse hot code replace not updating

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Why might simple changes to code fail to update? The 'hot code replace' message appears as usual when making big changes, but changing a println string, or commenting out a method call sometimes does nothing, and the app has to be restarted to apply the change. I think it may have something to do with native calls, but other than that there seems no pattern to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are not introducing changes that affect the class signature as Stephen mentioned, it should work. If it's not working, makesure that you have enabled 'Build Automatically' for the project (Project -> Build Automatically).

This is required for Eclipse to perform local builds when you do changes and push those to the server when you make a change.

Comment: Thanks, "Build Automatically" was what I've missed!

Answer (score 0):

Hot code replace does not allow you to change a class signature. That means, no attribute changes, no adding or removing methods, etc.

What you are allowed to do is to change a method's implementation.